# yocto project runqemu: command not found

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, yocto, qemu

I am setting up my yocto project, for that i have followed these below steps:

1. download the Poky Source code (ubuntu: /yocto/source)
   $ git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky
2. Checkout the latest branch/release (zeus)
   $ git checkout zeus
3. Step 3: Prepare the build environment (ubuntu: /yocto/source/poky)
   $ source oe-init-build-env ../../build
   The above script will move in a build folder and create two files in conf folder ( local.conf, bblayers.conf ) inside conf folder
4. Building Linux Distribution (unbuntu: /yoctu/build)
   $ bitbake core-image-minimal
5. Checking the runqemu (ubuntu: /yocto/source/poky/scripts)
   $ ls runqemu   // and it is there
6. Run generated image in qemu (ubuntu: /yocto/build)
   $ runqemu qemux86-64 core-image-minimal

other window open for qemu and image runs well.
**Problem**
After using first time when i close the terminal, and use it again by running **$ runqemu qemux86-64 core-image-minimal** in (ubuntu: /yocto/build)  error pops up **runqemu: command not found** and if i write bitbake in poky directory same error pops up bitbake: command not found.
**NOTE:** i have repeat this whole process 3 times to check if the installation is not correct but i have done everything fine from my side.

yocto project hierarchy:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you close your poky environment terminal you always `MUST` re-`source` the environment.

The poky's `oe-init-build-env` setups up all commands for you, for instance:

`runqemu*` commands which are present in `poky/scripts`.

The script also export `bitbake*` commands from `poky/bitbake/bin`.

The line responsible for that is in:

- **poky/scripts/oe-buildenv-internal** (line 99):

```sh
# Make sure our paths are at the beginning of $PATH
for newpath in "$BITBAKEDIR/bin" "$OEROOT/scripts"; do
    # Remove any existences of $newpath from $PATH
    PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed -re "s#(^|:)$newpath(:|$)#\2#g;s#^:##")

    # Add $newpath to $PATH
    PATH="$newpath:$PATH"
done
```

So, always if you open new terminal:

```sh
source /yocto/source/poky/oe-init-build-env /yoctu/build
```

**EDIT**

If you already have a build folder, make sure to provide the right path for that folder to the `oe-init-build-env` script.

If you provide new path to non-existing folder, than the script will create another build for you.

**EDIT2**

To source poky environment according to your path:

- Relative:

```
cd ~/Documents/yocto/source/poky
source oe-init-build-env build
                           ^
                           |
(because build is in same folder as the script)
```

- Absolute:

```
source /home/$USER/Documents/yocto/source/poky/oe-init-build-env /home/$USER/Documents/yocto/source/poky/build
```

**THE RULE**

```
source <path/to/oe-init-build-env> <path/to/build/folder>
```

If `<path/to/build/folder>` exists then, poky will source the existing build environment.

If `<path/to/build/folder>` does not exist, poky will create new build under the same name and path.

Comment: so according to you whenever i have to run the image first i have to run this command **oe-init-build-env** in /yocto/source/poky. one thing, last time when i run this command i make the build folder in /yocto not under poky folder. and now when i run this command it creates build folder. under that i have to again build the core-image-minimal. so what steps should i follow?

Comment: Check my **EDIT**

Comment: please see the yocto project hierarchy i have edit my question. now how can i provide right path for oe-init-build-env.

Comment: Check my **EDIT2**